# head :: tail pattern matching for strings

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Can I do something like this with a string:

```
s match {
  case "" => ...
  case head +: tail => ...
}
```

where `head` is the first character and `tail` is the remaining string?

In the above code the type of `head` is `Any`, and I would like it to be `String` or `Char`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`case h +: t` means `case +:(h, t)`. There is [object `+:`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.$plus$colon$) with `unapply` method.

Method `unapply` of object `+:` is defined only for `SeqLike` and `String` is not `SeqLike`.

You need a custom `unapply` method like this:

```
object s_+: {
  def unapply(s: String): Option[(Char, String)] = s.headOption.map{ (_, s.tail) }
}

"abc" match {
  case h s_+: t => Some((h, t))
  case _ => None
}
// Option[(Char, String)] = Some((a,bc))
```